# How to create custom product grid module in customer edit page in magento2?

Tags: admin, magento2.3.2, product-grid

I want to create a custom tab in the customer edit page in that tab displays the product grid. I don't know how to implement this task could you please help me?

Comment: on the customer account page?

Comment: Hi@Waqar Ali, thanks for your response. Please find below my required output screenshot. https://prnt.sc/q5ix3j. Please help me?